# Is it possible to activate ionic app on call

Tags: ionic-framework

I am not sure it is possible in ionic or not. What i want to do is create an app that can record user calls. so app must be activate when user make or get a call.

can anyone tell me if it is possible, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Beware this won't be an easy task but "never give up, never surrender". You'll want to use a variation of techniques first off this isn't an Ionic thing as much as it is a PhoneGap thing - ionic runs on phonegap.

Your workflow will look something like this:

- User opens your app sees a list of contacts
  (*the formatted names of contacts are different for android & ios so be prepared to test for this.
  http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/*)
- Contacts are displayed in ion-list user select one and phone's dialer launches *(use href=tel:xxxxx)*

From there you're going to want to trigger the audio capture plugin's API
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

To add the plugin to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
```

While it doesn't directly say it can record in call conversations it should still work.

It can definitely be done the storage space is also of concern, you'll have to set something in place to tell the user how many seconds/minutes they have the capacity to store.

That should get you started there will certainly be unforeseen nuances.

Good luck.

Comment: i already using these plugins. but thing is that after closing app how to activate this on phone call?

Answer (score 0):

We can record calls with **cordova-media-plugin** plugin in android.
First install the media Plugin by executing the following command
**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media**
Then goto the Plugin folder and traverse into the following file **“plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\android\AudioPlayer.java”** . Here in the **startRecording** function we have line
**this.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);** line number is 154
Change it to **this.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);**

We can replace MIC with any audio source in the following link. for example **VOICE_COMMUNICATION,VOICE_DOWNLINK,VOICE_RECOGNITION** etc
*https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html*